# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 1 pattern(s) tried: ['link/edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Tags: python, django, htmx

I am trying to use Django with HTMX. My task is to do editable row in the link list with HTMX. When I click the edit button in the row, I am getting NoReverseMatch error.

raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'link_update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['link/edit/(?P[0-9]+)/\Z']
[17/Oct/2023 12:54:42] "GET /link/edit/97/ HTTP/1.1" 500 118059

I've tried so many methods on stackoverflow but I didn't figure it out. Here my code is:

**urls.py in my project**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("user/", include("user_profile.urls", namespace="user")),
    path("link/", include("link.urls", namespace='link')),

]
```

**urls.py in my link app**

```
from django.urls import path
from link.views import tag_view, category_view, delete_links, delete_link, get_row_view, LinkUpdateView, LinkyListView


app_name = 'link'

urlpatterns = [
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', LinkUpdateView.as_view(), name='link_update'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/get_row_view/', get_row_view, name='get_row_view'),
    path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', tag_view, name='tag_view'),
    path('category/<slug:category_slug>/', category_view, name='category_view'),
    path('delete/', delete_links, name='delete_links'),
    path('delete-item/<int:pk>/', delete_link, name='delete_link'),
    path('list', LinkyListView.as_view(), name='link_list_view'),
]
```

**views.py in my link app**

```
def get_row_view(request, pk):
    link = LinkUrl.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = dict(
        link=link,
    )
    return render(request, 'link/row.html', context)

class LinkUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = LinkUrl
    form_class = LinkModelForm
    template_name = 'link/edit_link_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('link:link_update', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

**row.html**

```
<tr id="link_list_{{link.pk}}">
    <td>{{ link.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ link.get_full_url }}</td>
    <td>  
      <span class="p-1 border fs-12 rounded text-light bg-primary">
        <a href="{{ link.category.get_absolute_url }}" class="text-decoration-none text-light">
          {{ link.category }}
        </a>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>   
        {% for shortcode, tags in tags_by_shortcode.items %}
        {% if shortcode == link.shortcode %}
          {% for tag in tags %}
            <li class="list-inline-item border p-1 text-muted fs-12 mb-1 rounded">
              <a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}" class="text-decoration-none text-muted">
                {{ tag.title }}
              </a>
            </li>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </td>

    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" 
        hx-get="{% url 'link:link_update' pk=link.pk %}"
        hx-target="#link_list_{{link.pk}}">
        Edit
        </button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button
        class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-end"
        hx-delete="{% url 'link:delete_link' link.pk %}"
        hx-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this item?"
        hx-target="#link_list_{{link.id}}"
        hx-swap="outerHTML"> Delete
        </button>    
      </td>
  </tr>
```

**edit_link_form.html**

```
<td>
    <form hx-post="{% url 'link:link_update' pk=link.pk %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
          {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
         
          {% for field in form %}
               <td colspan="{{ form|length }}">
                    <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </td>    
          {% endfor %}
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" hx-get="{% url 'link:get_row_view' pk=link.pk %}" hx-target="#form-container"> Save </button>   
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </td>
    </form>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your error message highlights the problem:
`NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'link_update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found`. Specifically, an empty string is being passed when you call link.pk, rather than the primary_key (id) of the link.

Now the problem is not with the `hx-get` attribute inside your **edit** button; that is working because we can see from your traceback that clicking it makes a get request to the appropriate id (97).

So the error is inside the `edit_link_form.html` template, and most likely the `form` itself inside its `hx-post` attribute.

My suspicion is that because this template is rendered by the **'LinkUpdateView'** which inherits from **'UpdateView'** class, so you are encountering this issue because *'link'* does not exist in the context dictionary passed to the template --- instead it is referred to as *'object'*, which is the default context variable for the UpdateView.

So to fix this, inside `edit_link_form.html` change any reference to *link* to *object* (including the save button as well as the form), and hopefully you will be fine now (see below for full code):

**edit_link_form.html**

```html
<td>
    <form hx-post="{% url 'link:link_update' pk=object.pk %}"> 
    <!-- notice it is now 'object.pk' rather than 'link.pk' -->
        {% csrf_token %}
          {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
         
          {% for field in form %}
               <td colspan="{{ form|length }}">
                    <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </td>    
          {% endfor %}
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" hx-get="{% url 'link:get_row_view' pk=object.pk %}" hx-target="#form-container"> 
            <!-- as above, 'object.pk' rather than 'link.pk' -->
                Save 
            </button>   
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </td>
    </form>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The target id and the tr id in your html

```
hx-target="#link_list_{{link.pk}}">
```

and

Try to change them with:

```
hx-target="#link_list">
```

and

```
<tr id="link_list">
```

It is not common to put the row id in targets and in tags.
The id has to stay in the hx-get - hx-post - hx-patch - hx-delete - hx-put
to just to mention the CRUD concept.
It is a suggestion to keep in mind.

If you want to give a look to some Htmx example and demo here my own page

```
https://www.managepy.it/demo/
```

Comment: Afraid this is not necessarily true; in fact when Django is combined with HTMX to build a CRUD app, it's in fact very common to insert the instance PK dynamically into both the tag ID attribute and any related HX- attributes.

For example, the OP will likely have several `tr` elements inside his `table` element, probably as part of a List View. If he doesn't include the PKs dynamically into each relevant ID and HX-Target attribute, then HTMX will not know which elements to swap out when he makes a call.

The cause of OP's issue is Django-specific as per the above answer, not HTMX-specific.

Comment: @KingRan. Thanks for the correction to my comments.